# show-hide based on select option jquery wordpress

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript, dropdown

I am new in Wordpress and i have a big problem..
I want to create show-hide based on select option in specific page like this

http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/

But when i put my code i doesnt work... There is the option list but it doesnt work...
Should i install any script in function.php? Or should i use any plugin to make it work...
Thank you in advance

thats my code guys

https://jsfiddle.net/DopeAt/e63e3662/

```
        <select style="margin: 2% 0 3% 37.84%;" class="div-toggler" data-target=".Greekinfo">
          <option value="">Select game...</option>
<option value="agwn1" data-show=".agwn1">game 1</option>
<option value="agwn2" data-show=".agwn2">game 2</option>
<option value="agwn3" data-show=".agwn3">game 3</option>
<option value="agwn4" data-show=".agwn4">game 4</option>
<option value="agwn5" data-show=".agwn5">game 5</option>
<option value="agwn6" data-show=".agwn6">game 6</option>
<option value="agwn7" data-show=".agwn7">game 7</option>
<option value="agwn8" data-show=".agwn8">game 8</option>
<option value="agwn9" data-show=".agwn9">game 9</option>
<option value="agwn10" data-show=".agwn10">game 10</option>
<option value="agwn11" data-show=".agwn11">game 11</option>
<option value="agwn12" data-show=".agwn12">game 12</option>
<option value="agwn13" data-show=".agwn13">game 13</option>
<option value="agwn14" data-show=".agwn14">game 14</option>
<option value="agwn15" data-show=".agwn15">game 15</option>
<option value="agwn16" data-show=".agwn16">game 16</option>
<option value="agwn17" data-show=".agwn17">game 17</option>
<option value="agwn18" data-show=".agwn18">game 18</option>
<option value="agwn19" data-show=".agwn19">game 19</option>
<option value="agwn20" data-show=".agwn20">game 20</option>
<option value="agwn21" data-show=".agwn21">game 21</option>
<option value="agwn22" data-show=".agwn22">game 22</option>
<option value="agwn23" data-show=".agwn23">game 23</option>
<option value="agwn24" data-show=".agwn24">game 24</option>
<option value="agwn25" data-show=".agwn25">game 25</option>
<option value="agwn26" data-show=".agwn26">game 26</option>
<option value="agwn27" data-show=".agwn27">game 27</option>
<option value="agwn28" data-show=".agwn28">game 28</option>
<option value="agwn29" data-show=".agwn29">game 29</option>
<option value="agwn30" data-show=".agwn30">game 30</option>
```

```
    <div class="Greekinfo">
<div class="agwn1">
   <table style="margin-top: 10%;" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
<tr>
        <td>teamteamteamΑΕΚ</td>
        <td>teamteamΠαναιτωλικός</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΑΕΛ</td>
        <td>teamteamΒέροια</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΑ.Ο.Κέρκυρα</td>
        <td>teamteamΑτρόμητος Αθ.</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΑΕΠ Ηρακλής</td>
        <td>teamteamΑ.Ο Ξάνθη</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΛεβαδειακός</td>
        <td>teamteamΠΑΟΚ</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΟλυμπιακός</td>
        <td>teamteamΑστέρας Τρίπολης</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΠανιώνιος</td>
        <td>teamteamΠΑΣ Γιάννινα</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>teamteamΠλατανιάς</td>
        <td>teamteamΠαναθηναϊκός</td>
        <td>teamteam00/00/00</td>
        <td>teamteam00:00</td>
        <td>teamteamNova</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my JS code

```
            <script>
       $('select.div-toggler').change(function(){
           var target = $(this).data('target');
           $(target).children().addClass('hide');
         var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
        $(show).removeClass('hide');
               });
            </script>
```

Comment: What do you have in the JavaScript console?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DopeAt/e63e3662/  this is my code..... i installed scripts through Header and Footer Scripts plugin

Comment: Please include the code in your question. If someone with a similar problem finds this question in two years or so, the external link may not work anymore.

Comment: Yes Sir of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress runs jQuery in noConflict mode. This means that you have either have to use jQuery instead of $ or you can wrap the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    //jQuery code

});
```

The code at http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3898/ should work and uses the noConflict mode of jQuery. See http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3897/ for a wrapped version that allows you to use $. Both should work.

## Where to save the code?

You should *never* store the script in functions.php. Instead, create assets/js/your-script.js in your theme folder and store the code there. Add the following in your functions.php:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/your-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/